# Footer on Safari scrolls with content, but on Chrome it doesn't

Tags: html, css

When using safari, the footer scrolls with the content. However, when I switch over to chrome, it doesn't scroll and sits in the middle of the page. Here's the relevant code:

```
<footer>
    <div class="mastfoot">
        <div class="foot_class">
            <a href="--"><p>Facebook</p></a>
            <a href="--"><p>Email</p></a>
            <a href="--"><p>Linkedin</p></a>
            <a href="--"><p>Github</p></a>
            <a href="--"><p></p></a>
            </div>

    </div>
</footer>
```

---

```
html,
body {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    background: #457fca; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #5691c8, #457fca); /* 
    Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;

    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.mastfoot {
 color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

footer {
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: -150px;  /* negative value of footer height */
 height: 150px;
 clear: both;
}

    .foot_class {
    margin-top: 125px;
}
.foot_class a {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #2F3336;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: fontawesome;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.foot_class a:hover {
    background: #00b9b7;
}
.foot_class a:hover p {
    border-radius: 30px;
    bottom: 35px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.foot_class a p {
    color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -25px;
    right: -25px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    z-index: -1;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.6, 0.2, 1.5);
}
.foot_class a p:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

I really have no idea why this is happening. I'm pretty new to web dev, so I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake. If it helps, here's the url of the website: www.chrisrisley.us. It's a personal website I'm building for myself.

Comment: post fiddle of your code it may help to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anyway to see more of the code? Try playing with the position of the footer. You can try this and see if it helps.

```
footer {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -150px;  /* negative value of footer height */
 height: 150px;
 clear: both;
}
```

or

```
.mastfoot {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```